# php "SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']" correctness

Tags: php, server, port

In a code I write, which aims to provide more data about the user, I have difficulty collecting the user's port number.

I write in PHP.

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];

?>
```

While the user's IP address is easily collected by the command:`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`,

I get a port number that does not match the port number of the user, by using the command: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];`

Then, is the command `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`Supposed to provide the real port number of the user? Or does it just return a number randomly?

Is there a way to collect the user's port number correctly?

Thanks

Comment: how are you verifying that the port does not match? and: what do you even want to do with it?

Comment: Question. Why do you even care?

Comment: From what I understand, it's a random outgoing port from their router. It doesn't map to anything useful, and can change.

Comment: It is easy to check the port number by running WireShark and looking at the appropriate records. As I said, collecting data traffic about users on a particular platform, including IP address, user language, UserAgent, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']** is the port making the request on the user's machine.  That will be used to route back the page request to their router.  This may look like a random number, but it's a port generated by the user's router.

**$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']** is the port on your web-server that is receiving the request.  This will be either `80` or `443` depending on if the user is using https or not.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1055281/do-web-browsers-use-different-outgoing-ports-for-different-tabs) is another posted question on `Super User` that explains this phenomenon of browsers requesting a webpage from a "random" port -> https://superuser.com/questions/1055281/do-web-browsers-use-different-outgoing-ports-for-different-tabs.

Also, router in between the client and web-server may change the port and then store the port-connections in the NAT (network address table) in order to route the response back to the browser. -> https://superuser.com/questions/105838/how-does-router-know-where-to-forward-packet

**From: [CompTIA Security+ Get Certified Get Ahead: SY0-501 Study Guide](https://www.amazon.ca/CompTIA-Security-Get-Certified-Ahead/dp/1939136059/ref=sr_1_1?crid=22IKD744BHKK1&keywords=comptia%20security%2B%20get%20certified%20get%20ahead%20sy0-501%20study%20guide&qid=1562034320&s=gateway&sprefix=Comptia%20security%2B%20get%20cer%2Caps%2C167&sr=8-1) - 2017 by Darril Gibson**

> Client-side ports start at ports **49,152 and increment up to 65,535**.... 
>   ...When you use your web browser to request a page from a site, your
>   system will record an unused client port number such as 49,152 in an
>   internal table to handle the return traffic. When the web server
>   returns the web page, it includes the client port as a destination
>   port. When the client receives web page packets with a destination
>   port of 49,152, it sends these packets to the web browser application.
>   The browser processes the packets and displays the page.

Also, from the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php): https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> 'SERVER_PORT'
>       The port on the server machine being used by the web server for communication. For default setups, this will be '80'; using SSL, for
>   instance, will change this to whatever your defined secure HTTP port
>   is.
>
> 'REMOTE_PORT'
>       The port being used on the user's machine to communicate with the web server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I know the source you specified.
Still, I cross-checked the data that came up with WireShark and 100% of the time there was no match. what am I missing?

Comment: No match to what? Are you using Wireshark on the server or the client?

Comment: I think what you are seeing is that the router in between the client (device requesting the web-page) and the web-server also changes the requesting port. -> https://superuser.com/questions/105838/how-does-router-know-where-to-forward-packet.  The comment above "Why do you even care?" deserves some consideration.

Comment: client. I run wireshark on the client computer, and from it entered my platform.
Then I check wireshark data and data from my platform, and find that the port number is not compatible.

Comment: I'll edit my question to take into account the spirit of the original question.